# VBA excel event onworksheetopen global for every worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

How to trigger onworksheetopen event for every wokrsheet? I need to know Index number of active worksheet, but is a little bit dumb to write worksheet_open event in every worksheet. I want to make global function (Sub) in Workbook to trigger event every time when any worksheet is open to get it's index number

```
Sub WorksheetIndex()
Dim table As String
 Select Case ActiveSheet.Index
    Case 4
        table = "Trees"
    Case 5
        table = "Helps"
    Case 6
        table = "Plants"
    Case 7
        table = "Excavation"
    Case 8
        table = "Building"
    Case 9
        table = "Exterier"
    Case 10
        table = "Jobs"
    Case 11
        table = "Irrigation"
    Case 12
        table = "Instalation"
    Case 13
        table = "Systems"
    Case 14
        table = "Electronic"
    Case 15
        table = "Works"
    Case 16
        table = "Example"
    Case 17
        table = "Cars"

    End Select
    
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this `Event` code in `ThisWorkbook` code module, please:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   MsgBox Sh.Name & " - " & Sh.Index
   'You can use it as you need and eliminate the annoying message...
End Sub
```